# Best practices for creating android drawer

Tags: android, drawer

I'd like to use Drawer in my application that uses different views like TextView or multiple ListViews. I want to have similar Drawer like Gmail or Feedly apps:

[image]

[image]

However I couln't find any example of how to do this in code and XML layout. One of the problems is using multiple ListViews in ScrollView - should I use LinearLayout instead of them and style it to look and act like ListView? Also how do I handle click event on these various views?

Are there any good examples or best practises to look for when creating "rich" drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the usage of multiple listviews,yes use a layout and dividers(Views) and style them to look like a listview.Thats what the gmail app did.As for click events,you will handle them the same way you do on other activities,using the item id.